# Salesforce || Refused to connect to 'https://***********' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src 'self

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm facing the issue while Calling the api In LWC ( lightning web component)
even though i have added the base URL in CSP ( Content Security Policy ) And in Session Settings but still not understood what is the issue

API Call ->

```
    getApiDetails() {
        const baseUrl = "https://example.com";
        const payload = JSON.stringify({ "text": this.inputValue })
        fetch(baseUrl, {
            method: "POST",
            body: payload,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then(repos => {
                if (repos?.matched_answer === null) {
                    this.serchDetails = `there is no data exists against such keywords "${this.inputValue}"`;
                } else {
                    this.serchDetails = JSON.stringify(repos?.matched_answer?.answer);
                }
                console.log(this.serchDetails);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.error("error", error);
                this.serchDetails = error;
            })
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BoMZJ.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YizgH.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IDXk.png)

I went through the salesforce documentation

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that we cannot access from Salesforce any URL which contains an underscore (_). When you try to enter a URL with an underscore in remote site settings, you get the error below. I assumed there would be a simple solution to this, but after searching I've found nothing at all. Is there anything obvious what I'm missing?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.
Please do not comment in the answer and take the tour and read How to Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer